# Grails - Getting data from a different datasource and saving it in my Grails database

Tags: grails, datasource

I have a a Grails project that needs to retrieve data from a database that is running on a different project. This other project is running on a different platform(Drupal), and has different domains. I just need read some of the tables in this database, and save it on my own datasource.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: So you want to do SQL queries against the Drupal datasource, and use that data to populate and save Grails domain classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest way would be to use GORM's [support for multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources), which is intended to be used to partition your domain classes between two or more databases, but you don't have to assign any to this second datasource. One small downside would be that doing it this way will create an additional transaction manager, Hibernate session factory, and a couple more classes and Spring beans, but they won't take up much memory without anything using them. To do this, add a second `dataSource` block in `DataSource.groovy` with a unique suffix (it doesn't affect anything other than the Spring bean names), e.g.

```
dataSource_drupal {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = '...'
   username = '...'
   password = '...'
   url = '...'
}
```

Since this datasource won't be used for GORM you don't need to specify `dialect`, `dbCreate`, or `jmxExport`, and you don't need a second `hibernate` block, only the information needed to create the connection pool (it'll create 10 initial connections by default).

If you're concerned about the extra memory of this approach (you shouldn't be, it will be minimal) you can do a bit more work and register a Spring bean manually in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`. If you're using a recent version of Grails the datasource implementation is the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), so use its driver class and setter property names to specify the connection information. Use any valid Spring bean name, but I'd follow the conventions from the multiple datasources support:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

beans = {

   dataSource_drupal(DataSource) { bean ->
        bean.destroyMethod = 'close'

        driverClassName = '...'
        url = '...'
        username = '...'
        password = '...'

        // optional extra settings, not really needed
        // unless you expect a lot of usage
        initialSize = 42
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = false
        testOnReturn = false
        validationQuery = 'SELECT 1'
   }
}
```

So to use your second datasource, dependency-inject it into the service(s) you'll use to do the data migration work:

```
def dataSource_drupal
```

and to do the SQL queries, your best bet is `groovy.sql.Sql` since it does a great job of hiding most of the ceremony involved with JDBC code. Add an import

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```

and create a new instance passing the `DataSource` bean to its constructor so it can use that to get connections:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_drupal)
sql.eachRow('select name, bar from foo' ) { row ->
   Foo foo = new Foo(name: row.name, bar: row.bar)
   if (!foo.save()) {
       log.error "Validation error(s) for data $row: $foo.errors"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I set up the second data source as you mentioned, but I'm getting the following error when trying to run "Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_drupal)":  "Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:[interface java.sql.Connection] [interface javax.sql.DataSource]" What do you think I'm missing?

Comment: It's telling you the `dataSourceDrupal` variable is null, and it doesn't know which method to pass null to. So you need to fix the failing dependency injection. The name you use for dependency injection has to exactly match the name in `DataSource.groovy` or `resources.groovy` and must be a class-scope field, not a local variable in a method.