# Grails: Error creating bean with name 'properties': Bean definition is abstract

Tags: spring, grails, datasource

I'm new to Grails so I posted a question a few days ago on how to do a query to a different Datasource:
[Grails - Getting data from a different datasource and saving it in my Grails database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973833/grails-getting-data-from-a-different-datasource-and-saving-it-in-my-grails-dat/27976248?noredirect=1#comment44377405_27976248)

The answer above worked, but then I got a strange error when I tried to view or modify anything in my default datasource. In this case I tried to go to index view of my Client controller which uses some basic scaffolding:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory  - Bean couldn't be autowired using grails optimization: Error creating bean with name 'properties': Bean definition is abstract
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory  - Retrying using spring autowire
[http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - BeanIsAbstractException occurred when processing request: [GET] /EmmaRestServer/client/index
Error creating bean with name 'properties': Bean definition is abstract. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error creating bean with name 'properties': Bean definition is abstract
```

If I remove the second datasource, this problem disappears. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could you show how the two datasources are configured?

Comment: Yeah that was the reason. I had some configuration I did not need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some extra configurations in the resources.groovy. I removed them and now it looks like this, and it works properly:

```
beans = {
    dataSource_drupal(DataSource) { bean ->
        bean.destroyMethod = 'close'
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "user"
        password = "password"
        url = "jdbc:databaseURL
    }
}
```